# Unable to pull text out of a scraped HTML page with R XML package

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to extract the body of new york times movie reviews in order to do some semantic analysis on them. Unfortunately my HTML+R+XML package skills are not enough to get the job done. I can use the XML output from the NYT movies API to get movie details, but I can't work out how to use either the article API or a straight webpage scrape, in order to get to the body of the review.

WORKING code to the the movie details:

```
library(RCurl)
nyt.x.url<-'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.xml?query=The+Hangover&api-key=YOUR-OWN-FREE-API-KEY-GOES-HERE'
nyt.x.out<-getURLContent(nyt.x.url,curl=getCurlHandle())
library(XML)
a <- xmlTreeParse(nyt.x.url)
r <- xmlRoot(a)
# need to put the separate list items together into a mtrix, before they can be turned to a dataframe
nyt.df <- as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                    matrix(c(as.character(r[[4]][[1]][[1]][[1]])[6],  # display name
                             as.character(r[[4]][[1]][[3]][[1]])[6],  # rating - agrees with rotten tomatoes, but not imdb
                             as.character(r[[4]][[1]][[4]][[1]])[6],  # is it a critics pick
                             as.character(r[[4]][[1]][[5]][[1]])[6],  # is it a thousand best
                             as.character(r[[4]][[1]][[11]][[1]])[6],  # opening date
                             as.character(r[[4]][[1]][[15]][[1]][[1]])[6]),  # this is really the URL....
                           nrow=1,
                           ncol=6))

# now apply the right names
colnames(nyt.df) <- c("Title","MPAA-Rating", "Critics.Pick", "Thousand.Best", "Release.Date", "Article.URL")
```

I would then use this dataframe of movie details, to grab the review web page and try to grab the review text:

```
nyt.review.out<-getURLContent(as.character(nyt.df[6]),curl=getCurlHandle())
a2 <- htmlTreeParse(nyt.review.url)
```

But I can't figure out how to get to the full text of the review. I run into the same issue when I try to use the json API for articles (the url call to the api is below)

nyt.review.url <- 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v1/article?format=json&query=review+the+Hangover&begin_date=20090605&end_date=20090606&api-key=YOUR-OTHER-FREE-API-KEY-GOES-HERE'

Any help is greatly appreciated, but you will need to register for your own API keys (I have removed mine from the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this does what you want. There may be a way to do what you want directly from the API but I didn't investigate that.

```
# load package
library(XML)

# grabs text from new york times movie page. 
grab_nyt_text <- function(u) {
  doc <- htmlParse(u)
  txt <- xpathSApply(doc, '//div[@class="articleBody"]//p', xmlValue)
  txt <- paste(txt, collapse = "\n")
  free(doc)
  return(txt)
}


###--- Main ---###

# Step 1: api URL
nyt.x.url <- 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.xml?query=The+Hangover&api-key=YOUR-OWN-FREE-API-KEY-GOES-HERE'

# Step 2: Parse XML of webpage pointed to by URL
doc <- xmlParse(nyt.x.url)

# Step 3: Parse XML and extract some values using XPath expressions
df <- data.frame(display.title = xpathSApply(doc, "//results//display_title", xmlValue), 
                 critics.pick = xpathSApply(doc, "//results//critics_pick", xmlValue),
                 thousand.best = xpathSApply(doc, "//results//thousand_best", xmlValue),
                 opening.date = xpathSApply(doc, "//results//opening_date", xmlValue),
                 url = xpathSApply(doc, "//results//link[@type='article']/url", xmlValue),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df
#         display.title critics.pick thousand.best opening.date                                                                                           url
#1         The Hangover            0             0   2009-06-05                                       http://movies.nytimes.com/2009/06/05/movies/05hang.html
#2 The Hangover Part II            0             0   2011-05-26 http://movies.nytimes.com/2011/05/26/movies/the-hangover-part-ii-3-men-and-a-monkey-baby.html

# Step 4: clean up - remove doc from memory
free(doc)

# Step 5: crawl article links and grab text
df$text <- sapply(df$url, grab_nyt_text)

# Step 6: inspect txt
cat(df$text[1])
```

HTH

Tony Breyal

P.S. There's also an R package http://www.omegahat.org/RNYTimes but the website is down at the moment so I don't know what it's capable of.

Comment: That improves my working code, and with the addition of a trycatch here and there, will be even better. Thanks. HOWEVER, my problem is with the code in the penultimate paragraph, which is not formatted correctly and I can't correct on my iPad. The issue there is that I can't rip the HTML apart to get at the 6 or so paragraphs of the review, which is what I am after. (I want to run some sentiment analysis on movie reviews)

Comment: @AndrewDempsey Sorry mate, I don't quite follow. If you're asking how to get at the full text of the article through the API then I have no idea. My code does a screen-scrape (as per the "straight webpage scrape" in your question) to get at the main text of the article (I've now updated the code to just grab the paragraphs if that's want you mean?) :)

Comment: (Note to self - do not read code late at night on ipad)... @TonyBreyal - Apologies , I misread the code a bit last night. It's all good. Thanks mate.