# extract information from jsp page

Tags: r, jsp, web-scraping

I want to extract some information from a site like [this one](http://www1.map.gov.hk/gih3/index.jsp) which use jsp to host a GIS server and provide long-lat for geocoding of address. For example, search "ocean park" gives me the following (You need to click the "Show Coordinate" button on the map after you type and search the address):

```
HK1980 Grid
Northing (m):   810598
Easting (m):    835698

Latitude/Longitude(in WGS84)
Latitude(N):    22°14' 2.75"
Longitude(E):   114°10' 16.84"

UTM Grid
Northing (m):   2461463
Easting (m):    208420
Grid Reference: 50Q KK 084 614
```

But this is a bit time consuming if I need to enter all the addresses and copy all the output manually. I wonder if the process can be done by coding, preferably R. Is `RCurl` package needed? Thanks.

## update 01

I have toyed a bit of the site and managed to change the language of the site using this [link](http://www1.map.gov.hk/gih3/Map.do?action=en). Hope this will solve people's language barrier and help solving my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't read the language on that web site, but I have been playing around with scraping from xml and JSON api's as well as HTML pages. I have been able to do this with the following packages:

RCurl
JSONIO - parse JSON
XML - parse HTML and XML

An example of this is here: [Unable to pull text out of a scraped HTML page with R XML package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320525/unable-to-pull-text-out-of-a-scraped-html-page-with-r-xml-package)

Comment: I have modified the link above to make it english, do you have any clue of doing the stuff above in R? Thanks.

Comment: It all depends where the data is stored. if it is in the page source, then using rcurl will get you the page source and you have to parse it. If it does it dynamically with more calls back to the web server, then I have no clue. Sorry.